# What does "Document-oriented" vs. Key-Value mean when talking about MongoDB vs Cassandra?

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, nosql

What does going with a document based NoSQL option buy you over a KV store, and vice-versa?

Comment: Have a look at http://nosql-database.org/

Comment: That doesn't tell me when I Would use which and for what? When is it advantageous to use Mongo over Cassandra, or vice-versa?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

A *key-value store* provides the simplest possible data model and is exactly what the name suggests: it's a storage system that stores values indexed by a key. You're limited to query by key and the values are **opaque**, the store doesn't know *anything* about them. This allows very fast read and write operations (a simple disk access) and I see this model as a kind of non volatile cache (i.e. well suited if you need fast accesses by key to long-lived data).

A *document-oriented database* extends the previous model and values are stored in a *structured* format (a document, hence the name) that the database can understand. For example, a document could be a blog post **and** the comments **and** the tags stored in a denormalized way. Since the data are **transparent**, the store can do more work (like indexing fields of the document) and you're not limited to query by key. As I hinted, such databases allows to fetch an entire page's data with a single query and are well suited for content oriented applications (which is why big sites like Facebook or Amazon like them).

Other kinds of NoSQL databases include *column-oriented stores*, *graph databases* and even *object databases*. But this goes beyond the question.

#### See also

- [Comparing Document Databases to Key-Value Stores](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/659390374/comparing-document-databases-to-key-value-stores)
- [Analysis of the NoSQL Landscape](http://blog.knuthaugen.no/2010/03/the-nosql-landscape.html)

Comment: Key-value stores don't have to be done with a disk access and calling them non-volatile is incorrect in some implementations. You can create a key-value store in memory with no write-through or write-back to a non-volatile storage medium. Calling the data long-lived is misleading as well because the lifetime of the data has nothing to do with the manner in which you retrieve it.

Comment: This definition may be a bit of a misnomer. Basically both are key-value stores only. In one case the "value" is opaque the database doesn't have any knowledge of what one puts inside in the value - one can query only by the key. In the other case ("document") the database understands what's put inside the value a bit better and indexes etc can be generated based on some attributes of the value and queried for later..

Comment: I wonder how AWS's DynamoDB fits into this distinction. AWS claims DynamoDB is key-value DB, but it allows indexes to be created and items to be queried by *non-key" columns. Can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: @Skocdopole DynamoDB doesn't *really* allow queries on non-key columns does it? It basically does a scan of the entire database and filters on the results according to the query. I understand DynamoDB allows us create secondary indexes, but these take its own separate time to be created - which makes me think DynamoDB is then indexing all of the records separately - essentially creating a new 'key-value' representation maybe?

Answer (score 25):

Well, I've been investigating NoSQL myself the past month or so. I think it generally could be stated something like

- KV stores doesnt know of the value
  content actually stored for a key
- Document based lets you define secondary
  indexes within the value content, as
  the db knows the document structure
  (e.g. tags of a blog post).
- NoSQL solutions each have specific features which should be taken into consideration, such as

  - Special datatypes in a KV store (e.g. sets with left/right pop/push like in redis)
  - easy scale up/down cluster as riak says it has (I havent tried it ... yet)
  - pluggable data store as in Voldemort
  - build-in web configuration and web app support like in CouchDB / couchapp

Answer (score 5):

The biggest difference is that a document-oriented database supports secondary indexes, K/V does not. In general, document-oriented dbs tend to allow richer queries, allowing things like range queries, sorting, and other types of "advanced" operations.

Comment: Cassandra will support secondary indices in the next release (0.7)

Answer (score 1):

1. In the key-value database model, users can choose what the keys are, whereas the document
   identifiers in the document model are typically system-generated.
2. The key-value pairs in the key-value database model cannot be grouped whereas, in a
   document database, we can group key-value pairs into separate documents; moreover, some
   forms of document databases allow us to even group these documents further, namely into
   so, called "collections" or "domains".
3. While the documents in a document database have an internal structure that is clearly
   defined (and, thus, can be operated on by the DBMS; for instance, to create indexes), the
   same is not the case for the values in a key-value database where any possible internal
   structure of such values is opaque from a DBMS perspective.
4. In the key-value model, access to multiple database entries (key-value pairs, in this case)
   requires separate requests. In the document model, on the other hand, multiple database
   entries (documents, in this case) may be retrieved in a single request.